# Django - any way to fetch foreign key objects instantly?

Tags: python, database, django, foreign-keys

I've got a question about foreign key behaviour in Django.

I've defined a tree hierarchy in my models, where a parent-son relation is represented as a foreign key in the son model. Now, starting at the leaf level, I'd like to retrieve the parent, the parent's parent etc. as the objects I've defined.

This is possible by simply calling Leaf.objects.all() and accessing the objects normally from Python code.

But here come the troubles. For each such call, Django makes a SELECT query for the appropriate foreign ID. This is obviously terribly slow and inefficient. I'd like to tell Django something like *"hey, just fetch me all the data including the foreign keys at once, just do the joins and all the stuff at the database side"*. Is that somehow posible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
Leaf.objects.select_related().all()
```

Comment: @karthikr - that's true. I wanted to make clear it returns a queryset and can be further chained.

Comment: A child has exactly 1 parent (if not at the top level), although a parent can have up to n children. I used the same approach as in [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/), where the reporter-article relation is described.

Comment: @Danstahr - You are completely right. I was thinking about a completely different case. I removed the "side note" - it didn't make any sense here.